# Per-host background colour

Tags: variables

Having got a bunch of custom colors defined (thanks to [Drew](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41687/)), I need to use them to customize the background color per host. I have named the colors after the hostname, eg

```
(setq pentacle "#314159")
(setq athame "#271828")
```

so then I tried (at the bottom of the .emacs file)

```
(set-background-color (nth 0 (split-string (system-name) "\\.")))
```

but on (for example) pentacle.mydomain.com I get the message in the minibuffer

```
Undefined color: "pentacle"
```

I assume I need one or more additional levels of indirection in expanding the system name and splitting off the first token from the FQDN, but I can't see how to do this so that it gets recognized as the variable I defined.

Answer (score 7):

The path you have chosen introducing symbols to keep the colors requires you to convert the names you get by `system-name` to those symbols and evaluate them to get the color.

You could achieve this by

```el
(set-background-color
 (symbol-value (intern (nth 0 (split-string (system-name) "\\.")))))
```

Although doable I think the above is rather unconventional.

A more conventional approach would keep the mapping of machine names to colors in a structure like an association list.

Your example could be implemented as follows.

```el
(setq colors-for-machines
      '(("pentacle" . "#314159")
        ("athame" . "#271828")))
```

Retrieve the right value:

```el
(set-background-color
 (cdr
  (assoc (nth 0 (split-string (system-name) "\\."))
         colors-for-machines)))
```

Comment: No need for `eval`; just call `symbol-value`.

Comment: Great answer. You not only showed how to do what the OP was trying to do; you showed the better and more typical way to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and edits!  In particular the change to `symbol-value` and syntax highlighting!